# Why is HG command line running slow even for local access?

Tags: windows, command-line, mercurial, tortoisehg

Just typing 'hg' results in a 15 second response time to show me the list of commands.
I've tried uninstalling TortoiseHG and installing a newer version. I even uninstalled tortoise and installed just the command line. Same result.

I ran procmon over the exe and it showed that the slowness is in accessing the library.zip file which I believe is the python modules. It is fast when reading, but it has approx 0.3 second lag when it attempts this line:

Operation: CreateFile
Path: C:\Program Files\Mercurial\library.zip
Result: SUCCESS 
Detail: Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened

This line occurs often enough with the same delay each time to be the cause of this problem.
I ran procmon on another developer's machine and it has the same line, but it happens instantly. Other than that it seems to make all the same read/writes as mine.

I'm unsure what file it would be creating, seems a little odd. Still, its a real PITA to wait 15 seconds on every HG operation. Just doing a pull and update is now 30 seconds!

Its worth mentioning that this used to work fast and I'm unsure of what's different now. It was fine as much as a week ago and I've not installed any new software on my machine since then.

Other details of possible interest: 
- I run with local admin privileges
- UAC is enabled
- HDD is a toasty SSD and machine is only a few months old
- Process CPU is not maxing out as far as I can tell but certainly some spikes
- Plenty memory available

Any other hints? This is killing my productivity as you can imagine.

Comment: This question is a little open-ended and it is better to ask them on mercurial@selenic.com where people can offer suggestions and do further debugging. StackOverflow is for "How do I do X?" questions where one can give a precise answer.

Comment: Hi Martin, I didn't realise my question was open ended. It seems very specific: "Why is HG command line running slow even for local access?". I then proceeded to identify all investigations I had done and information discovered. Hopefully its something that a python or mercurial expert will have seen before and have a very specific answer for.

Comment: I liked your debugging, it was much better than most I've seen! However, I think it's difficult to say what is wrong without further discussion (asking you to try this or that) and this is where a mailinglist works better, IMHO. I've worked with Mercurial for years and I haven't seen your problem before.

Comment: Probably a virus scanner?

Comment: I was about to suggest defragging, in case the .zip is spread around the drive, but on an SSD that wouldn't do much.  Incidentally, the first run of `hg` on my work machine can take a few seconds, but after that it's speedy, I guess due to caching, so maybe something has changed with your drive access?  Or maybe the fact that the SSD is "toasty" is the issue - cool drives run much better :)